# How can I solve this problem with the screen touches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like you to tell me if there is an event that returns to me when it was the last time a user touched the screen, since I need a function to run 3 seconds after the user touched the screen for the last time

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. There are events for registering touch. And you can execute something after a certain time with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). To help you further, we expect you to try to create a solution to your question, or at least an attempt. If you get stuck, show your code, tell what part of the code malfunctions and ask the question again. For future reference read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific event for your use-case. What you can do however is adding a **click** event listener to your window object and assign the current time to a global variable as soon as someone clicked the screen. Additionally you have to use JavaScript's `setInterval()` method, which executes a function periodically e.g. every 20 ms. Inside it's callback function you can compare the current time to the time stored in the global variable and if the difference is bigger than 3000 trigger your action.

Here's an example (just click 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var timeClicked;

function screenClicked() {
  timeClicked = new Date();
}

function check() {
  if (timeClicked != null) {

    if (new Date() - timeClicked > 3000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      alert("time's up!");
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener("click", screenClicked);
var interval = setInterval(check, 20);
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#eeeeee"><span>click anywhere inside this window</span></body>
```